# How do I break out of the loop at anytime with a keypress

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, break, pyautogui

I'm on Windows 10, VSCode, Python 3.9

My program is an infinite loop that moves my mouse around the screen.
Currently my code allows me to exit the program in between mouse movements, but not mid mouse movement. I want to be able to break at anytime with a keypress.

```
import time
import pyautogui
import keyboard
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
pyautogui.PAUSE = 0
var = 1

while var == 1:

if keyboard. is_pressed('b'):
    break
else:
    pyautogui.moveTo(384, 216, 0.5)

if keyboard. is_pressed('b'):
    break
else:
    pyautogui.moveTo(1536, 216, 0.5)

if keyboard. is_pressed('b'):
    break
else:
    pyautogui.moveTo(1536, 864, 0.5)

if keyboard. is_pressed('b'):
    break
else:
    pyautogui.moveTo(384, 864, 0.5)
```

This is my first question on here so please let me know if my formatting is wrong. Also if anyone has recommendations to make my code prettier I will gladly accept.

Comment: Generally, you can kill a running code with Cntrl + C or Cntrl + Z on Windows, I'm not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: You need multi threading - eg. multiprocessing https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: One idea would be to use [`keyboard.on_press_key`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardon_press_keykey-callback-suppressfalse) to do something (like changing the value of `var`) as soon as the target key is pressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, threading is a good way to go:

```
import threading
import time
import keyboard

def move_mouse(arg):    # simulate a blocking function call, like pyautogui.moveTo()
    print("moving {}".format(arg))
    time.sleep(arg)

def loop_through_moves():
    while True:
        move_mouse(1)
        move_mouse(2)
        move_mouse(3)

t = threading.Thread(target=loop_through_moves)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

while True:
    if keyboard. is_pressed('b'):
        break
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I'll definitely research threading since it looks useful for other projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit on ctrl-C you can use a `try:` `except:` call like this:

```
import sys
import time
import pyautogui
import keyboard
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
pyautogui.PAUSE = 0
var = 1

try:
    while var == 1:
        if keyboard. is_pressed('b'):
            break
        else:
            pyautogui.moveTo(384, 216, 0.5)
        
        if keyboard. is_pressed('b'):
            break
        else:
            pyautogui.moveTo(1536, 216, 0.5)
        
        if keyboard. is_pressed('b'):
            break
        else:
            pyautogui.moveTo(1536, 864, 0.5)
        
        if keyboard. is_pressed('b'):
            break
        else:
            pyautogui.moveTo(384, 864, 0.5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

This way should allow you to exit the program by pressing `ctrl-C` AKA `KeyboardInterrupt``

PS: Ctrl-C should auto kill your program but this does that!